# Change the Tracking Information Shipment # to Order #

Tags: shipping, template, shipment-tracking

I'm trying to change the pop-up window when customers track their orders, the pop-up currently shows:

"Shipment #" I would like to change this to the actual order number.

I have tried the following:

```
 <h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Order #'),$_order->getRealOrderId();?></h2>
```

But it doesn't load.

The original file is located in:

> default/template/shipping/tracking/popup.phtml

How can I display the Order # instead of the Shipment # on this pop up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/shipping.xml to find the block for this template.

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="shipping/tracking_popup" name="shipping.tracking.popup" template="shipping/tracking/popup.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Now if you take a look at `Mage_Shipping_Block_Tracking_Popup` you will notice that you can not get the order object directly.

So in your template file try this before your code above

```
 $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
```

Comment: I see your logic but the order number is coming up blank.

Comment: Try `$this->getTrackingInfo()->getOrderId();` instead of `$this->getOrderId()` because it is deprecated after 1.3.2.3

Comment: no luck, adding that code, stops the page from loading

Comment: Take a look at `popupAction()` in app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/controllers/TrackingController.php. What is the content of $shippingInfoModel. See `Mage_Shipping_Block_Tracking_Popup::getTrackingInfo()`

Answer (score 4):

I had nearly the same problem and needed some information from the shipment address of the order for a tracking link. The following code worked for me in the popup.phtml (Magento 1.9.1.0):

```
$shippingInfoModel = Mage::getModel('shipping/info')->loadByHash($this->getRequest()->getParam('hash'));
if (array_key_exists('order_id', $shippingInfoModel->_data)) {
    $order_id = $shippingInfoModel->_data['order_id'];
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
}
if (array_key_exists('ship_id', $shippingInfoModel->_data)) {
    $ship_id = $shippingInfoModel->_data['ship_id'];
    $order_shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($ship_id);
    $order = $order_shipment->getOrder();
}
```

Using $order you can get now the order number: $order->getIncrementId();